# Get row counts of a table from datacontroller in Tizen? And is any kind of sqlite operation possible for datacontroller?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

**First part:**
I have a dataController with UIAPP that can make simple database operations that are mentioned in datacontroller [doc](https://github.com/Samsung/tizen-docs/blob/master/docs/application/native/guides/app-management/data-control.md). However I need to access data table row count, I'm inserting data with AUTO_INCREMENT KEY. So I want to access all elements and dump table when done. In mysql server I can `SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.bigTransactionHistory;` to access rows count. But I do not see how to do that with datacontroller provider.

So how can I get row counts of a table from database?

**SECOND PART :**  And is there a way to execute any sqlite command with datacontroller provider?
For example can we do this?

```
char* sql_command = "any command";
ret = sqlite3_exec(db, sql_command, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

How can we access any function from data controller provider service to the UIAPP?

I'm asking second part because `data_control_provider_sql_cb` has limited number of execution functions.

Answer (score 0):

**First Part**: You can use below API with 'NULL column_list', then you can select all columns

```
/**
 * @brief Creates SQL SELECT statement.
 *
 * @since_tizen 2.3
 *
 * @remarks The specific error code can be obtained using the get_last_result() method. Error codes are described in Exception section.
 * @param[in] provider The provider handle
 * @param[in] column_list The column names to query \n
 *                        Pass @c NULL if all columns need to be selected**
 * @param[in] column_count The total number of columns to be queried
 * @param[in] where A filter to select the desired rows
 * @param[in] order The sorting order of rows to query
 *
 * @return The SQL SELECT statement on success,
 *         otherwise NULL
 * @exception #DATA_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE Success
 * @exception #DATA_CONTROL_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER Invalid parameter
 * @exception #DATA_CONTROL_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY Out of memory
 */
char *data_control_provider_create_select_statement(data_control_h provider, const char **column_list, int column_count, const char *where, const char *order);
```

**Second Part** : You can use the Bulk API. Please refer to reference
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/mobile/5.5/group__CAPI__DATA__CONTROL__CONSUMER__MODULE.html#gaf8891d1ab8c938ada38f9668c2c9fa52